# Is it possible to get value of a method thru Property

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, propertyinfo

I have to export data to Excel programmatically. I have a class with several properties. I was wondering if it's possible to retrieve values of all properties using a loop. For instance:

```
public class SqueezeProperties
{
    public int WidthField { get; set; }
    public string Width_unit { get; set; }
    public int ResPressure { get; set; }
    public int DensityField { get; set; }
    ......
 }
```

While writing to excel, I code as:

```
 t = typeof(SqueezeProperties);
 foreach (PropertyInfo field in t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
                oSheet.Cells[r, c++] = field.Name;
```

Now to input values, is there any way that I can iterate and find values of all properties that can be accessed, and store them in excel?

I doubt if it is even possible.  I just taught myself how to access the property name & its details, so I thought maybe the other thing could also be possible and I am simply unaware of it.

Thanks

Comment: `field.SetValue`? Not sure what your question is, just remember that reflection calls can be time consuming also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`PropertyInfo.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue.aspx).

(However according to specification the order of your properties is not guaranteed to be the same as the definition order. So to be safe you might want to order them.)

---

Also instead of getting them via reflection you could create a collection manually instead, this would take care of the order already.

e.g.

```
var properties = new Expression<Func<SqueezeProperties, object>>[]
{
    o => o.WidthField,
    o => o.Width_unit,
    //...
};
foreach (var exp in properties)
{
    var mem = (MemberExpression)exp.Body;
    var prop = (PropertyInfo)mem.Member;

    oSheet.Cells[r, c++] = prop.GetValue(squeezePropertiesInstance, null);
}
```

Comment: How do you order them ? And I don't want to set the values, I want to retrieve values from the object and display them.

Comment: @Tvd: Then use `GetValue`. Concerning the ordering you would have to have some reference list of the names in order for example. This being the case you might as well use the second method.